# Hightcharts Packed Buble chartt for angular 6

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular6

I am trying to access and display the Packed bubble chart using angular:
Link: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/packed-bubble

### code for the chart:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bu-packedbubble',
  templateUrl: './bu-packedbubble.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bu-packedbubble.component.css']
})
export class BuPackedbubbleComponent implements OnInit {
  //
  Highcharts = Highcharts; // required
  //
  buData = [
    {
      name: 'mlisa-qa',
      node_count: 4,
      domains: [
        {
          name: 'wade1'
        },
        {
          name: 'wade2'
        },
        {
          name: 'wad12'
        },
        {
          name: 'wade'
        }
      ]

    },
    {
      name: 'alphanet',
      node_count: 2,
      domains: [
        {
          name: 'alphanet-12'
        },
        {
          name: 'alphanet-122'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'bugbash',
      node_count: 4,
      domains: [
        {
          name: 'bugbash-bash',
          zones: [
            {
              name: 'tommy_zone',
              access_point_groups: [
                {
                  name: 'default',
                  access_points: [
                    {
                      name: ''
                    }
                  ]

                },
                {
                  name: 'default12'
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              name: 'sam_zone',
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
  //
  chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'packedbubble',
      height: '100%'
    },
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      packedbubble: {
          minSize: '20%',
          maxSize: '100%',
          zMin: 0,
          zMax: 1000,
          layoutAlgorithm: {
              gravitationalConstant: 0.05,
              splitSeries: true,
              seriesInteraction: false,
              dragBetweenSeries: true,
              parentNodeLimit: true
          },
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              format: '{point.name}',
              style: {
                  color: 'black',
                  textOutline: 'none',
                  fontWeight: 'normal'
              }
          }
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Network',
        data: [
          {
            name: 'Domain1',
            value: 4
          },
          {
            name: 'Domain2',
            value: 450
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

On browser console I am geetting the following error:
[image]

It looks like the type: 'packedbubble', is not found.

I using the following verion of highcharts libraries version, with angular verison 6:
- "highcharts": "^7.2.1",
- "highcharts-angular": "^2.4.0",

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code is as follows since I am using Angular Version 8:

```
//
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
//
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bu-packedbubble',
  templateUrl: './bu-packedbubble.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bu-packedbubble.component.css']
})
export class BuPackedbubbleComponent implements OnInit {
  //
  Highcharts = Highcharts; // required
  //
  buData = [

  ];
  //
  chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'packedbubble',
    },
    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      packedbubble: {
          minSize: '20%',
          maxSize: '100%',
          zMin: 0,
          zMax: 1000,
          layoutAlgorithm: {
              gravitationalConstant: 0.05,
              splitSeries: true,
              seriesInteraction: false,
              dragBetweenSeries: true,
              parentNodeLimit: true
          },
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
              format: '{point.name}',
              style: {
                  color: 'black',
                  textOutline: 'none',
                  fontWeight: 'normal'
              }
          }
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: 'Network',
        data: [
          {
            name: 'Domain1',
            value: 4
          },
          {
            name: 'Domain2',
            value: 450
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Mind the import of Highcharts module and require of Highcharts-more:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(Highcharts);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you haven't imported the highcharts-more module which is required for packedbubble series.

Example:

```
declare var require: any;

import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";

import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import * as HighchartsMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";


HighchartsMore(Highcharts);

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  Highcharts = Highcharts;


  chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'packedbubble',
    },
    series: [{
      data:         [{
        name: "Poland",
        value: 298.1
    },
    {
        name: "France",
        value: 323.7
    }],
    }
    ]
  };

}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-6ly2j

Comment: I with the line: "HighchartsMore(Highcharts);" I am getting the error:  This expression is not callable.
 Type 'typeof import("/Users/thobishimoreko/Documents/Projects/bu-angular/bu-angular-ruckus-analytics-v8-react-integration/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts-more")' has no call signatures.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian Wedzel, Thanks for the instructions I managed to import ave the following inplace and it workds: import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(Highcharts);